# Error when using Redux toolkit's isAnyOf - TypeError: matcher is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying out the [Matching Utilities](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isanyof) in Redux Toolkit, and when I use `isAnyOf` I get this error.

[image: error]

I'm using React with Redux.

my code is:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, isAnyOf } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
```

```
builder
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(getAllData.fulfilled, addQuestion.fulfilled, getQuestion.fullfilled, updateQuestion.fulfilled),
        (state) => {
          state.connectionError = null
        }
      )
```

Dependency versions:

"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.5"

Do you think it may have anything to do with dependency versions?

I tried using `isAllOf` instead, and it doesn't show any error, but I need to use `isAnyOf`.

Any tip is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the version of the `@reduxjs/toolkit`

Comment: @slideshowp2 it's ^1.2.5. I included it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

So I just had this error as well. After a bit of trouble shooting, I realised that the error can be produced if any of the arguments you pass to the isAnyOf function are not functions. In my case, I was passing a mixture of actions defined in the redux toolkit reducer and actions defined by createAsyncThunk. I had accidentally put .fulfilled on the end of one of the reducer actions and this was what caused the error.