# Redux Toolkit matching utilities (isAllOf) not capturing the state change

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm following the example in the official doc [Matching Utilities](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities), and trying to use `isAllOf` to update state when all the API calls have been successfully made. All the parameters will be created by `createAsyncThunk`, i.e.:

```js
export const fetchCart = createAsyncThunk(
  "api/fetchCart",
  async (payload, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      // Replace with your actual API call logic
      const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/cart");
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  },
);
```

and the way I'm calling it is similar to:

```js
// src/store/pageStatusSlice.js
import { createSlice, isAllOf, isAnyOf, isRejected } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fetchCart } from "./cartSlice";
import { fetchProduct } from "./productSlice"; // Import your thunks

const pageStatusSlice = createSlice({
  name: "pageStatus",
  initialState: {
    isLoading: false,
    success: false,
    error: false,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(isAllOf(fetchProduct.pending, fetchCart.pending), (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addMatcher(
        isAllOf(fetchCart.fulfilled, fetchProduct.fulfilled),
        (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = false;
          state.success = true;
        },
      )
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(fetchCart.rejected, fetchProduct.rejected),
        (state, action) => {
          console.log(action);
          state.error = true;
        },
      );
  },
});

export default pageStatusSlice.reducer;
```

The rejection case is working, but not with the pending and fulfilled case, seems like both pending and fulfilled cases are not triggered.

When there is only 1 parameter passed in the `isAllOf`, it works fine.

I checked [Error when using Redux toolkit's isAnyOf - TypeError: matcher is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663684/error-when-using-redux-toolkits-isanyof-typeerror-matcher-is-not-a-function), in the code snippet provided in this question, it seems like it's using the matching utilities in the same way:

```js
builder
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(getAllData.fulfilled, addQuestion.fulfilled, getQuestion.fullfilled, updateQuestion.fulfilled),
        (state) => {
          state.connectionError = null
        }
      )
```

The answer from the question above mentioned he accidently put `.fulfilled` at the end of the action and it was causing error, but in the official doc seems like using `.fulfilled` is allowed:

```js
import { createReducer, isAllOf } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
  isSpecialAndInterestingThunk,
  initialState,
  isSpecial,
  isInteresting,
} from '@virtual/matchers' // This is a fake pkg that provides the types shown above

const loadingReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addMatcher(
      isAllOf(isSpecialAndInterestingThunk.fulfilled, isSpecial),
      (state, action) => {
        state.isSpecial = true
      }
    )
    .addMatcher(
      isAllOf(isSpecialAndInterestingThunk.fulfilled, isInteresting),
      (state, action) => {
        state.isInteresting = true
      }
    )
})
```

I have also created a code sandbox with a simple example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-dewdney-crdqdz?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isAllOf` means "is all of these at the same time".

So `isAllOf(fetchProduct.pending, fetchCart.pending)` means "it's an action for a pending `fetchProduct` thunk and a pending `fetchCart` thunk at the same time".
Which is literally impossible.

You probably want to use `isAnyOf` which means "is one of these things" instead.

Comment: I never saw "is all of these at the same time" before. It's very useful if docs have this line

Comment: @lamhungypl From the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities
isAllOf - returns true when all conditions are met; isAnyOf - returns true when at least one of the conditions are met